# limiting the records inserted in a sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the requirement to build a asp.net sign up form which will allow students to register a training. So far I built a database in sql server and 3 tables: `student`, `training` & `studenttraining`

My question is, how can I limit the form from displaying the dates available once a particular training gets full, or meabe how can I prevent by checking the tables that the user can register?

Comment: show query which selects available dates

Comment: I have not came out with a query yet , but just wondering how would I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
Select count(*) as SeatsFilled, t.TrainingKey, t.TrainingDate
From Training t
Inner Join StudentTraining st on t.TrainingKey = st.TrainingKey
Group By t.TrainingKey, t.TrainingDate
Having count(*) < t.TotalSeats
```

TotalSeats is a column in the Training table that specifies how many seats the training provides.  I assumed StudentTraining is a many-to-many bridge table between Students and Training.

Comment: right now, the structure of my jointtable is    id,  student_id , training_id ,   which other fields do I need to add?

Comment: You will need a TrainingDate and TotalSeats fields in your Training table. Just replace TrainingKey in my query with Training_Id.

Comment: training currently I have     training_id   pk,   traning_name, date, time, seats_Open.   meabe I am going the hard way...

Comment: @user Why do you think that is hard?  That should be fine if seats_open is the original number of seats open.  Just add the training_name to the query above and swap in field names as appropriate.  If on the other hand you are updating seats_open everytime someone enrolls, then your query is just: `Select training_name, date, time Where seats_open > 0`

Comment: Yeh, I assume you would want Training_ID as the item value for the drop down and Training_name for the item text

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to establish what "full" is first. Then, you can do a simple 
`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table` to determine if the full amount is already reached.

Comment: I have a list of dates and times where the course will be taught . If that course is available at date , and that time, then is available

Comment: You should also be tracking enrollment I presume. In this case, count it.

Comment: right, well the only requirement for the system is to record the enrolled studetns and times, and to stop a student from enrolling in an unavailable date or time

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could have a MaxTraining column in the training table and when you get the data for your form, you can count the training entries in studenttraining, and if it equals MaxTraining, then don't bring that training entry, cause it means it's already full.